# "(1:k) Tree-Matching" - Solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

Some months ago there was a [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519462/maximum-bipartite-graph-1-n-matching) regarding a "**1:n matching problem**" and there seems to be no poly-time algorithm.

I would like to add constraints to find a maximum matching for the 1:n matching problem with a polynomial algorithm. I would like to say: "For vertex A1 choose either {B1,B2,B5} or {B2,B3} if the vertices are not already taken from another A-vertex" i.e. I would not allow all possible combinations.

This could be expressed if we introduce helper vertices H for each choice and substitute edges with trees => we get a problem similar to the ordinary bipartite matching. Every vertex of A or B can have only one edge in the matching. The edges to or from vertices in H are either all in the matching or none of them is present in the matching. Imagine the following tri-partite graph:

[image]

Now define h_ij="tree rooted that contains H_ij" to express the matching easily:

- Then in the example M={h12,h22} would be one 'maximum' matching, although not all vertices from B are involved
- The set {h12,h23} is not a matching because then B3 would have be choosen twice.

Would this problem then be solvable in polynomial time? If yes, is there a polytime solution for the weighted (w(h_ij)) variant? If no, could you argue or even proof it for a "simple-man" like me or suggest other constraints to solve the 1:n matching problem?

E.g. could the graph transformed to a general graph which then could be solved with the weighted matching for general graphs? Or could [branchings](http://cis.poly.edu/suel/papers/branch.pdf) or even [matching forests](http://books.google.com/books?id=mqGeSQ6dJycC&pg=PA1006&lpg=PA1006&dq=matching+forest&source=bl&ots=xOLSJ-dnPf&sig=kMwwFRAejcLwxOUHj0tRXs9NZ3k&hl=en&ei=QMaLS6SGHdLz_Aby5PXpBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CCUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=matching%20forest&f=false) help here?

PS: not a homework ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between maximal and *maximum*. I have assumed you meant maximum for the below writeup.

You don't seem to have defined your problem very clearly, but if I have understood your intent correctly,  It seems like your problem is NP complete (and 'equivalent' to [Set Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing)).

We can assume that the allowed sets sizes is the same (k) for all A_i to find a [1:k] matching, as any other set size can be ignored. To find max k, we just run the algorithm for [1:k] for k = 1,2,3.. etc.

So your problem is (I think...):

Given m set families `F_i = {S_1i, .., S_n(i)i}` (|F_i| = size of F_i = n(i), need not be same as |F_j|), each set of size k, you have to find one set from each family (say S_i) such that

- S_i and S_j are disjoint for any i neq j.
- number of  S_i's is maximum.

We can show that it is NP-Complete for k=3 in two steps:

1. The NP-Complete problem [Set Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) can be reduced it. This shows that it is NP-Hard.
2. Your problem is in NP and can be reduced to Set Packing. This and 1) implies your problem is NP-Complete. It also helps you leverage any approximation/randomized algorithms already existing for Set-Packing.

Set Packing is the problem:

Given n sets S_1, S_2, ..., S_n, find the maximum number of pairwise disjoint sets among these.

This problem remains NP-Complete even if |S_1| = |S_2| = ... = |S_n| = 3 and is called the 3-Set packing problem.

We will use this to show that your problem is NP-Hard, by providing an easy reduction from 3-Set packing to your problem.

Given S_1, S_2, .., S_n  just form the families

F_i = {S_i}.

Now if your problem had a polynomial time solution, then we get a set of Sets {S_1, S_2, ..., S_r} such that

- S_i and S_j are disjoint
- Number of S_i is maximum.

This easy reduction gives us a solution to the 3-set Packing problem and thus your problem is NP-Hard.

To see that this problem is in NP, we reduce it to Set-Packing as follows:

Given F_i = {S_1i, S_2i, ..., S_ni}

we consider the sets T_ji = S_ji U {i} (i.e. we add an id of the family into the set itself) and run them through the Set-Packing algorithm. I will leave it to you to see why a solution to Set-Packing gives a solution to your problem.

---

For a *maximal* solution, all you need is a greedy algorithm. Just keep picking up sets till you can pick no more. This would be polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I corrected the 'maximal' mistake according to your suggestion and now I will read your answer carefully :-)

Comment: sorry for my vague definition of the problem :-( hmmh, I meant that k could be still different for each vertex in A. But if a 'static' k is already NP complete ... I don't assume too much for my wider range problem definition.

To your explanation: Do you meant that n(i) is the number of trees/choices per vertex in A? And the only difference to the 1:1 matching is that the 1:1 problem is a 2-Set packing problem, right? And what do you mean with T_ji = S_ji U {i}: which vertex do we use to extend S_ji and why?

Comment: Yes n(i) is the number of choices per A. Yes 2-Set packing is maximum matching. Each set is {u,v} where the edge is between u and v in the graph. Suppose A1 was allowed S_11 = {B1,B2,B5} and S_12 = {B2, B3, B7}, then the new sets you make are T_11 = {B1,B2,B5,A1} and T_12 = {B2,B3,B7,A1}. Because of the presence of A1 in both these sets, you can choose at most one among them, when you find a Set-Packing.

Comment: ah, ok! Thanks a lot for all the clarifications! Now I understand the basics of your proof :-) I hope I will understand the "NP reduction" this week ...

Comment: Now that I am a bit more comfortable with the NP-complete class stuff, I have one more question: How will the proof looks like if we have a polytime matching (i.e. |S_1|=|S_2|=|S_3|=..= 1), at which step the proof will fail?

**BTW**: I think you mean that k could be 2 or greater and even then problem is NP complete - instead of 3 or greater, right? Because of the presence of A_i in all sets!?

Comment: @Karussell: No, I mean k>=3, as proving NP-Hardness requires taking an NP-Complete problem (in this case 3-Set Packing) and reducing it to your problem. You seem to be confusing it be going the other way round. I don't understand your first question.

Comment: ok. For the first question I meant: there are special graphs and circumstances where the maximum independent set problem could be solved in polytime. e.g. see this
http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2002/12_2002.ps
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_graph#Independent_sets

Now: why can I be sure that the 1:k treematching is not such a special graph which can be used in polytime? E.g. because it has no claws?

Comment: We can reduce 3-Set packing to the general "1:k" tree matching. Of course, you could impose additional constraints to change that. No idea what constraints though. Sorry.